# Suvival shooter enemies wont add score

Tags: unity-game-engine

In my survival shooter tutorial, I just finished adding the ScoreManager. I copied the scripts exactly as is, but the `ScoreManager` will never recognize that the score has increased. I've added debugging on the `ScoreManager` and `EnemyHealth` scripts to see if the score is actually increasing, and believe me, it isn't.

Here's the EnemyHealth script:

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.AI;

public class EnemyHealth : MonoBehaviour
{
    public int startingHealth = 100;            // The amount of health thee nemy starts the game with.

    public int currentHealth;                   // The current health the enemy has.

    public float sinkSpeed = 2.5f;              // The speed at which the enemy sinks through the floor when dead.
    public int scoreValue = 10;                 // The amount added to the player's score when the enemy dies.
    public AudioClip deathClip;                 // The sound to play when the enemy dies.

    Animator anim;                              // Reference to the animator.
    AudioSource enemyAudio;                     // Reference to the audio source.
    ParticleSystem hitParticles;                // Reference to the particle system that plays when the enemy is damaged.
    CapsuleCollider capsuleCollider;            // Reference to the capsule collider.
    bool isDead;                                // Whether the enemy is dead.
    bool isSinking;                             // Whether the enemy has started sinking through the floor.

    void Awake()
    {
        // Setting up the references.
        anim = GetComponent<Animator>();
        enemyAudio = GetComponent<AudioSource>();
        hitParticles = GetComponentInChildren<ParticleSystem>();
        capsuleCollider = GetComponent<CapsuleCollider>();

        // Setting the current health when the enemy first spawns.
        currentHealth = startingHealth;
    }

    void Update()
    {
        // If the enemy should be sinking...
        if (isSinking)
        {
            // ... move the enemy down by the sinkSpeed per second.
            transform.Translate(-Vector3.up * sinkSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
        }
    }

    public void TakeDamage(int amount, Vector3 hitPoint)
    {
        // If the enemy is dead...
        if (isDead)
            // ... no need to take damage so exit the function.
            return;

        // Play the hurt sound effect.
        enemyAudio.Play();

        // Reduce the current health by the amount of damage sustained.
        currentHealth -= amount;

        // Set the position of the particle system to where the hit was sustained.
        hitParticles.transform.position = hitPoint;

        // And play the particles.
        hitParticles.Play();

        // If the current health is less than or equal to zero...
        if (currentHealth <= 0)
        {
            // ... the enemy is dead.
            Death();
        }
    }

    void Death()
    {
        // The enemy is dead.
        isDead = true;

        // Turn the collider into a trigger so shots can pass through it.
        capsuleCollider.isTrigger = true;

        // Tell the animator that the enemy is dead.
        anim.SetTrigger("Dead");

        // Change the audio clip of the audio source to the death clip and play it (this will stop the hurt clip playing).
        enemyAudio.clip = deathClip;
        enemyAudio.Play();
    }

    public void StartSinking()
    {
        // Find and disable the Nav Mesh Agent.
        GetComponent<NavMeshAgent>().enabled = false;

        // Find the rigidbody component and make it kinematic (since we use Translate to sink the enemy).
        GetComponent<Rigidbody>().isKinematic = true;

        // The enemy should no sink.
        isSinking = true;

        // Increase the score by the enemy's score value.
        ScoreManager.score += scoreValue;

        // After 2 seconds destory the enemy.
        Destroy(gameObject, 2f);
    }
}
```

Here is the ScoreManager:

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System.Collections;

namespace CompleteProject
{
    public class ScoreManager : MonoBehaviour
    {
        public static int score;        // The player's score.
        Text text;                      // Reference to the Text component.

        void Awake()
        {
            // Set up the reference.
            text = GetComponent<Text>();

            // Reset the score.
            score = 0;
            Debug.Log("score reset");
        }

        void Update ()
        {
            // Set the displayed text to be the word "Score" followed by the score value.

            Debug.Log(score);
            text.text = "Score: " + score;

            if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.V)) 
            {
                score += 10;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The Score should increase when enemy dies, but for some reason it wont. I know this because in the ScoreManager I've added Debug.Log to print out the value of score every frame. I can press V (added for debug) and my score value increases, but normally it does not.

Comment: You only add score when enemy starts sinking, here: `ScoreManager.score += scoreValue;`. You don't modify it in `Death` method so it don't increase when they die from hp loss.

Comment: @trollingchar I added that in the death method and it dosent change anything

Comment: I can't see a reason why it wouldn't work in your code. Just add `StartSinking();` to your `Death` void

Comment: @AliBaba Still wont work